# Creating UIView in UITableViewController that doesn't moves with the table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I would like to display a small `UIView` with some text in the center of a `UITableViewController` when I call the `showHud` method.

```
- (void) showHud {

    UIView *paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 120, 30)];
    [paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:paintView];

}
```

Actually the problem with this code is that the view doesn't stays on its place, when I scroll the `tableview` it goes up with cells. Is it possible to pin it somehow?

Comment: You need start with a ViewController, in side this you put your tableView (as a subview of your viewController.view), and now you can add another subview a your viewController.view just above of the tableView. (Don´t forget implemente de delegate and dataSource protocols, and put your viewController as delegate of your tableView).

Comment: @OnikIV I must use a UITableViewController, I've tried to do that way with Storyboard, but I couldn't move the tableview under the view.

Comment: Ensure you are trying to add a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController`. Don't try to add a `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController`.

Comment: @bushiko If you don't want change your viewController from TableViewController to viewController, You need to add your view a UIWindow directly (It's heavy), but I think you don't have other option.

Comment: @OnikIV how you mean it's heavy? Can it cause performance issues?

Comment: Well if you don't cath all ways to go back or go forward, in order to remove this view for the windows, the previous/next viewController will have this same view on the top, due to this view is on the top of the application windows view. (Of course there will be a bunch of object, than they will be deallocate property). But it`s not a performance issue, it's a posible bad user experience issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that with a UITableViewController because the view property of such controller is a UITableView, so the content will always scroll with it.

You need to create a regular UIViewController and add a UITableView to that controller's main view. Then anything else you add to that main view, will stay in place as it is outside of the table view.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method and change the frame of `paintView` according to tableview offset.

eg:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset
  [paintView setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150+offset.y, 120, 30)];
}
```

But the best way would be to create a simple UIViewController.
You must use `UItableViewController` because of pullToRefresh controller?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom table view class that works only with UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

UI could add a view to the window and position it to the very front:

```
UIView testView = [[UIIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame].size.height - 85 , 75, 75)]; [[[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow] contentView] addSubview:testbox]; addSubview: testView]; testView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `UITableViewController` is typically embedded in a "parent" view controller, like `UINavigationController`. Its `UITableView` will then have a superview, like `UINavigationControllerWrapperView`. Even if your table view controller is a root view controller, the table view's superview is `UIWindow`.

So you can safely assume that your table view always has a superview. Then add your `UIView` to this superview instead of the table itself:

```
//Note: frame should be different here as it's in the superview's coordinate system
UIView *paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 120, 30)];  
[paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view.superview addSubview:paintView];
```